# SFMC/Exact Target c# SOAP API - is there a way to assign tracking folders to email send definitions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, c#

I'm creating an email send definition for a user-initiated send with the c# SOAP API library.  Is it possible to assign the tracking destination folder through the API?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean assign a parent folder so you can find the user-initiated send inside that folder?  Every folder has a FolderID,  you can achieve this by sending a UpdateRequest for User-Initiated Send object with property "CategoryID" set to desired FolderID

Comment: Thanks @Bobio.  I should have made my request more clear.  If you are in the Marketing Cloud UI, I'm looking for how to assign the folder under Tracking -> Sends.

Comment: I had a quick look http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/emailsenddefinition/  it doesn't seem to provide that tracking folder property. "The Additional property contains external campaign ID information or additional metadata that appears in the tracking extract, and there is a personalization string for it. You can set the information contained in this property at the time of the send or within an email send definition."  Maybe have a look the first property "Additional" see if you can create tracking extract? This is beyond my knowledge.