# SFMC/Exact Target Fuel SOAP API - is there any way to create scheduled email send definition in to custom folder instead of My Tracking folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk

I'm scheduling created email send definition from user-initiated folder with the node js Fuel-SOAP API library, this gone to My Tracking directory Is it possible to assign the tracking destination custom folder through the API?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you mouse over your custom folder you should see a numeric folder id in the link.  In  your soap request, use that ID in EmailSendDefinition.**CategoryID** property

Updated with example

```
var folderID = 12345;
            var sendESD = new ET_EmailSendDefinition
            {
                AuthStub = myclient,
                CustomerKey = newSendDefinitionName,
                CategoryID = folderID
            };
            var sendESDResponse = sendESD.Send();
            Console.WriteLine("Send Status: " + sendESDResponse.Status.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Message: " + sendESDResponse.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Code: " + sendESDResponse.Code.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Results Length: " + sendESDResponse.Results.Length);
```

Comment: I have tried your way but i have no luck. Can you please explain it with brief, or suggest me another solution, because I am stuck on this.

Comment: @KrishanKantSharma see updated example. you need to get the folderID from SFMC UI

Comment: No luck . I should have made my request more clear. If you are in the Marketing Cloud UI, I'm looking for how to assign the folder under Tracking -> Sends.
Same thread is here : 
[link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142585/sfmc-exact-target-c-soap-api-is-there-a-way-to-assign-tracking-folders-to-ema?rq=1)