# How can I programmatically create/change the tracking destination for emails in an automation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs, automationstudio, marketingcloudapi

I've been working on a few scripts that can build out all the pieces of an automation that I need to create fairly often.

I can create/update DEs, queries, email send activities, but I CAN'T seem to *change* the tracking destination in those email send activities.

It always defaults to "my tracking", and I've found changing it in the UI sets it with a "tracking category id" parameter, but I can't seem to set that via SSJS/api etc.

The point of this is to have as close to a "1 click install" as possible, and if I need to go into each send definition manually to change the tracking folder to the correct one it really gets away from that. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142585/sfmc-exact-target-c-soap-api-is-there-a-way-to-assign-tracking-folders-to-ema

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping since those were asked 5 years ago that maybe they either were wrong or that something had been updated since then.